# Theme hooks vs module hooks

Tags: hooks

Sometimes when I try to apply a hook, just to realise it's supposed to be in a module file.

Is there a way of knowing what hooks can be implemented in a theme's template.php file, or one in a module?

Comment: Generally when a hook is not available to be overridden in a theme it is for good reason. Themes should only be for code relating the display of the content and functionality that the modules provide. Code that adds/removes/changes functionality or content usually should be in a module. Also think about the fact that if you change themes you lose any customisations made in template.php, so if you are making changes that you would likely want to keep if you ever changed themes then that would definitely want to go in a module.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally speaking, only alter hooks can be implemented by themes, which means hooks like `hook_form_alter()` and `hook_menu_alter()`, or in short all those hooks that are invoked through [`drupal_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/drupal_alter/7) in Drupal 7 and lower ([`ModuleHandler()::alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ModuleHandler.php/function/ModuleHandler%3A%3Aalter/8.7.x) or [`ThemeManager::alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Theme%21ThemeManager.php/function/ThemeManager%3A%3Aalter/8.7.x) in Drupal 8).

Other hooks, which are invoked by [`module_invoke_all()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/7) ([`ModuleHandler::invokeAll()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ModuleHandler.php/function/ModuleHandler%3A%3AinvokeAll/8.7.x) in Drupal 8), don't get invoked for themes simply for fact the code doesn't check if the currently enabled theme defines any hook.

```php
  foreach (module_implements($hook) as $module) {
    $function = $module . '_' . $hook;
    if (function_exists($function)) {
      $result = call_user_func_array($function, $args);
      if (isset($result) && is_array($result)) {
        $return = array_merge_recursive($return, $result);
      }
      elseif (isset($result)) {
        $return[] = $result;
      }
    }
  }
```

In Drupal 8, where the [`ModuleHandler`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21ModuleHandler.php/class/ModuleHandler/8.7.x) class invokes hooks implemented from modules and the [`ThemeManager`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Theme%21ThemeManager.php/class/ThemeManager/8.7.x) class invokes hooks implemented by themes, only the first class implements `invoke()` and `invokeAll()`. This means that in Drupal 8 theme hooks aren't invoked, by Drupal core.

This is valid for Drupal core hooks, and mostly all the hooks used by contributed modules. It is then up to a module to verify a hook is implemented by a theme too, and invoke it. This is what the Views module does.

```php
  // Let modules modify the view just prior to rendering it.
  foreach (module_implements('views_pre_render') as $module) {
    $function = $module . '_views_pre_render';
    $function($this);
  }

  // Let the themes play too, because pre render is a very themey thing.
  foreach ($GLOBALS['base_theme_info'] as $base) {
    $function = $base->name . '_views_pre_render';
    if (function_exists($function)) {
      $function($this);
    }
  }
  $function = $GLOBALS['theme'] . '_views_pre_render';
  if (function_exists($function)) {
    $function($this);
  }
```

For hooks used by contributed modules, you need to check the code used to invoke hooks. Chances are that, for themes, only the alter hooks are invoked; in some cases, other hooks could be implemented by themes.

Keep in mind that in the case of themes, not all the enabled themes are checked for hook implementations, contrary to what happens with modules. Only the currently used theme and the base themes are checked, as done from the Views module.

Comment: hook_entity_view_alter() doesn't work in themes.

Comment: At least in D7 alter-hooks in themes are only invoked if the theme has already been initialized in the same request (ie. by calling `theme()`). If it hasn’t been initialized no alter hooks in any theme will be executed.

Comment: @zwirbeltier Theme hooks are invoked for the theme used to render the page. `theme()` doesn't change the theme used for the page, but it invokes a function to render data. It doesn't change the theme, for example, from Garland to Minelli.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: If you look at the code in `drupal_alter()` you see that it only invokes alter-hooks in the theme if `drupal_theme_initialize()` was called before. If it wasn’t then there is no active theme (yet) and thus no hooks called. At least in D7 there is no guarantee when `drupal_theme_initialize()` is called the first time in a request.

Comment: @zwirbeltier The theme set from Drupal is already initialized when a page is rendered. If a module sets a theme for a page without calling the appropriate function, it's its responsability to initialize it.

Comment: @kiamlalune: That’s certainly not true for Drupal 7: Whether or not the theme is likely to be already initialized depends strongly on the specific alter-hook we are talking about. For example: Try figuring out if `hook_element_info_alter()` is always invoked after `drupal_theme_initialize()`.

Comment: See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2448843